How to properly type a mock.fn() in node test runner using TypeScript?
I am using node:test with TypeScript and I want to mock a function in my unit test.
// file.ts
type ArgFnType = (arg1: CustomType1, arg2: CustomType2) => Promise<CustomType3>

export function fnToTest(argFn: ArgFnType) {
  doSomethingWithArgFn(argFn);
}

// file.test.ts
import { mock } from 'node:test';
import type { Mock } from 'node:test';
import { fnToTest } from './file.js';

const mockedArgFn: Mock<???> = mock.fn(() => Promise.resolve(fakeReturnValue));

// this throws the TypeScript error: Mock<???> is not assignable to ArgFnType
fnToTest(mockedArgFn)

My question is: In the example above, what should I put into the ??? of Mock<???>.
I've tried a couple of options:

Just do Mock without passing a type. This throws an error saying that Mock needs a type argument.
Import ArgFnType and use Mock<ArgFnType>. This will make TypeScript complain that my mock implementation does not match ArgFnType. I don't want my mock implementation to re-create every arg and return property, that's the point of the mock...
Mock<Function>. This throws the error Mock<Function> is not assignable to ArgFnType.
Mock<(...args: any[]) => unknown>. Mock<(...args: any[]) => unknown> is not assignable to ArgFnType.
Mock<(...args: any[]) => any>. This actually doesn't throw any TypeScript error, but triggers a lint violation for the "no explicit any" rule.

It seems like Option 5 is the only thing I've found that TypeScript won't complain about, but it also feels wrong to ignore a lint violation.
Does anyone have a better alternative?

As a rule of thumb, use generic types where possible to have type inference, jest.fn<ArgFnType>(...)

Don't type it. There is one rule of thumb: when you want to enforce what you get, type; when you don't want to enforce, don't type, the type will be infered by TypeScript.

@EstusFlask this project is not using jest, it is using node:test.

@EricMORAND what specifically should I not type? If I don't type the mockedArgFn, TypeScript still complains. I'm not in control of the code that types the ArgFnType. It's already typed and I can't un-type it since it's third party code.

@EricMORAND Without additional typing, the inferred type of mockedArgFn will be incompatible with ArgFnType, this is what the question describes

@onlywei Something I didn't notice, but the reason is that Node's test api is modeled after Jest, this is why it looks the same, so the comment still applies, it's mock.fn<ArgFnType>(...). Actually you can expect the support of generics from any kind of TS code that was written in recent years. In case of doubt, check the types first https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/test.d.ts#L1000 Much easier to do this in IDE

@EstusFlask Your comment gave me a lot of hope. You're saying do: mock.fn<ArgFnType>(...) instead of const mockedArgFn: Mock<ArgFnType> = mock.fn(...), correct? I just tried it out and the TypeScript result is the same: it complains that my mock implementation is incomplete and not assignable to ArgFnType.

Yes. It's not shown what's ArgFnType in details so it's unknown how exactly they are incompatible and how far you can go, i.e. fakeReturnValue and CustomType3. The next step is mock.fn(( () => Promise.resolve(fakeReturnValue) ) as ArgFnType). If this doesn't work, try as unknown as ArgFnType

@EstusFlask ArgFnType is a function that expects one or more arguments, but my mock implementation returns the same value regardless of arguments. Additionally, my mock implementation only returns one of the properties in the fakeReturnValue type. Those are the incompatibilities.

It's not shown what fakeReturnValue and CustomType3 are. If fakeReturnValue
is incompatible with CustomType3, you'll naturally have problems with type compatibilty. You need to correctly type it in the first place, then there will be less problems with typing a function

@EstusFlask CustomType3 is an object like { a: string; b: number; }. fakeReturnValue is { b: 12 } without providing the property "a" because the unit test doesn't care about that property.

Would likely be Promise.resolve(fakeReturnValue as CustomType3) or probably where fakeReturnValue is defined

I had to solve this by adding the missing properties in my fakeReturnValue even though the test doesn't care about those values at all. CustomType3 is actually an inline type and so it's not importable and it's a pain to re-create.
I still don't like this solution because it feels like TypeScript forced me to add properties to a mock that I don't need. Somehow jest mocks are able to magically mock functions without their types and have it still work in a way that node-test mocks are not able to.

@EstusFlask, I meant writing this: const mockedArgFn = mock.fn(() => Promise.resolve(fakeReturnValue));

Jest has different TS types and afaik they are more unsafe for historical reasons, this is why it allows you to do things you aren't supposed to do. You need to achieve type safety by providing proper types but you certainly don't need to add properties you don't need. This should be solvable with "as": https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYBVwQMxQLxQDeUAhgFxRIBOAlgHYDmA3FAEYV1yqsRUsC+AKFCQoAQSoMAYnUyiCACgCU+AHxQAClTQ0EEADzwkaOTlWCAbiSpQAZnQoTpsrPijK1m7al0QAdFQQCMgANhYQCsTsUACMAExQ-KQIsIgoGFjYSiyCQA . In more severe cases of incompatibility you'd need "as unknown as"

Did you try const mockedArgFn = mock.fn(() => Promise.resolve(fakeReturnValue as CustomType3)) as suggested above? What was the error?
